# Please suggest better way to write this code without making callback hell

Tags: node.js, mongoose, callback, nested

```
router.get('/:id',ensureLogin,(req,res)=>{

    somemodel.findOne({...}) ****//mongoose call 1****
    .then(result=>{
   
        if(some condition){
            User.findOne(some condition) ***//mongoose call 2***
            .then(result=>{
                 //Some code is to be executed here using the "User.findOne..."
                }
                res.render('some template')
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
        else{
            res.render('some another template');
        }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.render('error/500');
    })    
})
```

Here mongoose call 2 depends on mongoose call 1 for some reason. Though the code is working yet I want it to be framed properly. So please suggest a better way for doing this. I hope I cleared enough the query.
Thanks.
PS: I'm a newbie in NODE.js

Answer (score 1):

You would benefit from using `async/await`, particularly with conditionals involving different asynchronous execution branches which you have.  It also makes it a bit easier to have centralized error handling for the different asynchronous code paths:

```
router.get('/:id', ensureLogin, async (req,res) => {
    try {
        let result = await somemodel.findOne({...});
        if(some condition){
            let secondResult = await User.findOne(some condition);
            //Some code is to be executed here using the "User.findOne..."
            res.render('some template')
        } else {
            res.render('some another template');
        }
    } catch(e) {
        res.render('error/500');
    }    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171899/i-am-unable-to-refactor-the-code-appropriately , Please look into this. @Terry Lennox

Answer (score 1):

The asynchronous nature of a lot of Node.js calls can be very confusing at first, but you get used to it quite quickly and realize that it's a great technology.

I'd suggest using the [async / await](https://javascript.info/async-await) syntax, this makes the code much more like synchronous code. It certainly makes it a lot easier to follow.

I'd refactor the code to something like this:

```
router.get('/:id', ensureLogin, async (req,res) => {
    try { 
        let result = await somemodel.findOne({/* search criteria */});
        if (someCondition(result)) {
            let user = await User.findOne({/* search criteria */})
            res.render('some template');   
        } else { 
            res.render('some another template');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.render('error/500');
    }
})
```