# I am unable to refactor the code appropriately

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
router.get('/',ensureLogin,async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        let result = await Mock.find();
            result.forEach(async (e)=>{
                if(e.attemptedBy.includes(req.user._id)){
                    let a_Mock = await User.findOne({_id:req.user._id,"attemptedMock.setNo":e.setNo},{attemptedMock:1});
                    e.status="Attempted";// not accessible on template as res.render executes first
                    e.marks = a_Mock.attemptedMock[0].totalMarks;  //not accessible
                    console.log(a_Mock.attemptedMock[0].totalMarks);         
                }
                else{
                    e.status = "Unattempted";//it is accessible
                    console.log('else block')
                }
            })
           console.log("second log");
           res.render('dashboard',{mocks:result});//I want this code to be executed when the "result" is updated by "forEach" block
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
})
```

Console logs as : 1. "else block" 2. "second log" 3."res.render executed"  4. "total marks", that concludes that res.render executed before "if block's" statement "e.status='Attempted'" so it is not accessible on template page. Please tell me how to refactor in a proper way.

Comment: If you are trying to serialize your loop (do one at a time), don't put `await` inside a `.forEach()` loop as `.forEach()` is not async-aware or promise-aware.  Just change the `.forEach()` to a regular `for` loop which will pause appropriately for the `await`.

Comment: Man! You saved my life :). After changing to "for loop" console logs as 1. else block 2. total marks 3. second log 4. res.render which solved the problem of rendering first before loop.  Please, Can you elaborate what exactly the logic is behind this workflow ?

Comment: I used async/await and for loop after your suggestion. Is the code structure is okay now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do your loop one at a time and then call `res.render()` after the loop is done, then the easiest way to do that is to use a regular `for` loop as it will actually "wait" for the `await`.  `.forEach()` is not promise-aware so, while the callback itself will wait for the `await` before it finishes, `.forEach()` itself will not and it will run the entire loop and then the next line after it will run and then each individual callback will finish sometime later.  That will cause you to call `res.render()` before any of the `.forEach()` callbacks are done.  For this reason, you pretty much never want to use `.forEach()` with promises as it's just not promise-aware.  Instead, use a regular `for` loop like this:

```
router.get('/', ensureLogin, async (req,res) => {
    try {
        let result = await Mock.find();
        for (let e of result) {                
            if (e.attemptedBy.includes(req.user._id)) {
                let a_Mock = await User.findOne({_id:req.user._id,"attemptedMock.setNo":e.setNo},{attemptedMock:1});
                e.status = "Attempted";
                e.marks = a_Mock.attemptedMock[0].totalMarks;  //not accessible
            } else {
                e.status = "Unattempted";    //it is accessible
            }
        }
        console.log("second log");
        res.render('dashboard', {mocks:result});
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Note also that this code sends an error status in the `catch` block.  You need to always send some response to the incoming http request.

Comment: Got it Bro. Just one more issue. When I console.log (result) just above res.render, It must give output result with either "Unattempted" or "Attempted" property but It's not showing at all. But it is accessible on res.render. Also if I console (e) just after I set status to it in for block, it's not showing in console too. Works fine on template but just clear the doubt why It's happening so.

Comment: @DeepakSoni - I don't know why it wouldn't show in the `console.log()`.  Perhaps the property is marked as non-enumerable.  You could try outputting one directly such as `console.log(result[0].status)` and see if it shows that way.  Obviously, it's there since it works in the template.

Comment: Anyways, @jfriend00 Bro your knowledge worked as a charm. I'll keep bothering you with my queries . Thanks

Comment: @DeepakSoni - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

inside for each, you can wrap everything in function.

refernece :[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#:~:text=The%20Promise.,input%20iterable%20contains%20no%20promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#:%7E:text=The%20Promise.,input%20iterable%20contains%20no%20promises).

```js
processE = async(e)=>{

  try{
  
     if(e){
       await something
       e.something 1= somevalue
     }else{
         e.something 2= somevalue
     }
     
     return false
  }catch(err){
     //you can also throw depends on how u handle your err and type of promise.something you use
     return err
  }
}

let promises = []
e.forEach( (e)=>{

      promises.push(processE(e))

})
/// Promise.something you can take a look at reference and use ethe one behavior that you prefer.
const result = await Promise.all(promises)

//render here
```